# What does the number 4587 mean in Legends of Tomorrow Arrowverse

Tags: reference, arrowverse, legends-of-tomorrow

What does the number 4587 mean? In one episode of *Legends of Tomorrow*, it was the pass for Felicity's warehouse and in another it was a cell number.

Comment: As of Arrow Season 7, Oliver Queen is arrested and is inmate 4587

Comment: In season 2 episode 3, Moira Queen's case was 4587

Answer (score 11):

Marc Guggenheim, the creator of *Arrow* and *Legends of Tomorrow* answered this [on Twitter](https://twitter.com/mguggenheim/status/703041321485758464).

> @Iloveyoursoul I love the TV show, WISEGUY. 4587 was Vince Terranova's "ident code." Arrow & Legends both have lots of Wiseguy easter eggs.

[image: screenshot]